# PHP OpenSSL extension not working

Tags: php, wamp, httpd.conf

i'm installing the brand new typo3 6.2.9 on my localhost using WAMP on windows 8.1
**wampserver2.5**

- Apache-2.4.9
- Mysql-5.6.17
- php5.5.12-64b

i'm having this error

> PHP OpenSSL extension not working
>   Windows apache thread stack size

i did checked the steps that i should do open_ssl is working fine and i have already added the following lines to my httpd file under the apache server.

![enter image description here][1]

http://i60.tinypic.com/2m4dedd.jpg

have somebody an idea about where those errors coming from?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjvLl.png

Comment: I added the first image, please add the content of the second image as text into your question by editing it

Answer (score 0):

The Typo3 PHP OpenSSL extension error indicates [`openssl_pkey_new`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php) has failed to generate a new private key. Typo3 suppresses the error message in its pre-installation diagnostics, so you should run this function separately to seek the appropriate error message.

The issue may have to do with an invalid or missing OpenSSL configuration (`openssl.cnf`) as described on the [PHP OpenSSL extension page](http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php).